# Why does sodium citrate in water turn black when blueberries are added?

Tags: aqueous-solution, food-chemistry, medicinal-chemistry

I recently started making [oral rehydration therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_rehydration_therapy) for someone I'm taking care of who developed POTS after COVID-19 infection. (ORT was recommended by their doctor.) I use the standard ingredients of ORT: sodium chloride, sodium citrate, potassium chloride and dextrose/glucose. To add some flavor, I tried blending in some frozen blueberries, but when I did the solution instantly turned black. The water became cloudy and opaque as well. By trying to recreate the reaction methodically, making four different solutions of blueberries and one of the other chemicals in water, I determined that this was a reaction between the sodium citrate and something in the blueberries.

Despite its off-putting color, the solution still tastes fine. However, I'm hesitant to serve it to the person I'm caring for without knowing for sure if it's safe to drink! What causes this reaction, and is it safe?

Comment: 1.) yes, obviously harmless, 2.) we don't give medical advice here, 3.) find a new doctor, ORT is a method to make sure diarrhea patients (particulary cholera patients) get enough fluid.

Comment: As your solution contains sodium citrate, it is a little bit basic. As the blueberry juice contains an anthocyane dyestuff that changes color in basic medium, that is what you have made without knowing it. The anthocyanes takes a more bluish color if the solution is basic. That is the same phenomena that happens when cooking red cabbages : they turn blue when boiled in calcareous (or hard) water. This color change is safe and does not modify the taste.

Comment: It is "blueberry that turns black", or "a solution of sodium citrate in water when..."

Comment: @Karl you say 2) we do not give medical advice and 3) you just gave one.

Comment: @Maurice, that's very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @Karl, off topic but the reason was that ORT can apparently address hypovolemia by causing the body to retain more water in the bloodstream. Not sure if that's actually true but that's what they told us! Then again POTS can have several different causes so hypovolemia might not even be the issue.